# "Yo habría gustado ir pero no pude" o "Yo hubiera gustado ir pero no pude"

Tags: subjuntivo, conjugación, condicional

The sentence I would like to translate is:

> I would have liked to go, but I could not.

When translating this, I suggested the conditional form of `haber`: `habría`, but Google's translation suggests the subjunctive conjugation `hubiera`.

My question is: is one of these demonstrably correct? Are they both correct depending on context, and if so, what would an appropriate context for each be? The reason I chose conditional is there seems to be no uncertainty or frequency to the desire to go (to wherever), so I geared towards indicative.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You're not wrong in being confused: SpanishDict conjugation tables perhaps correctly translate "hubiera gustado" as "I had liked", even though all the usage examples I have found clearly mean "I would have liked".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Historically, the conditional is the *correct* (note the italics) form, but nowadays the subjunctive is also accepted and widely used, I would roughly say 50% and 50%. The same speaker can use either, regardless of any condition, context, etc.

By the way, you are using *gustar* incorrectly. Just check that out in your A1 level book ;)

Comment: Thank you for your response! Isn't `gustado` the participle form of `gustar`? In which case, doesn't `haber gustado` translate correctly to `to have liked`?

Comment: @Tom it's not the tense. You don't say "yo habría gustado ir", but "me habría gustado ir".

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Great for the clarification, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both are wrong. The right sentence is

> Me hubiera gustado ir

*gustar* uses an indirect object construct.

In English it would be something like:

> Going would have been liked TO ME

Comment: Thanks for your response! I understand from this and from the comments above that I certainly needed `me` rather than `yo`. Nonetheless, the main reason I asked was to distill the reason why `hubiera` is a better option than `habría`. Can you elaborate on why `me hubiera gustado ir` is better than `me habría gustado`?

Comment: You cannot translate _gustar_ like that. It doesn't mean ‘like’, but ‘please’, which in English takes a direct object (not an indirect one) that cannot be replaced with a prepositional phrase: Me habría/hubiera gustado ir = To go/going would have pleased me = I would have liked to go.

Comment: Of course. That is not correct english. It is a made up example easy to remember

Answer (score 0):

You can use all these phrases in the espefic context of your phrase.
An action in the past that not happen but you like it would be.

> Me hubiera gustado ir
>   
> Me hubiese gustado ir
>   
> Yo habria gustado de ir
>   
> Yo hubiera gustado de ir